# Write Contacts Name and Number In XML File in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget, xml-serialization

I am beginner to android and coding I want some help.I want to display contacts number and name in XML file on Sdcard .I already got contacts , created XML file and write some tags using "serializer" separately but didn't be able to write the require info in XML file altogether, I searched and tried allot kindly help me in this regard.Thanx